# Execute a program/script during build

Tags: unity-game-engine

For instance, I have some documentation generator and I want Unity to generate fresh docs (execute it) after every compilation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a post build script.

Unity will call any c# editor class method marked as [PostProcessBuildAttribute](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html).

Eg:

```
public class MyBuildPostprocessor {
    [PostProcessBuildAttribute(1)]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject) {
        // Execute your external script here
        // Eg: ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        }
}
```

Or use the older (Mac only) [PostprocessBuildPlayer](http://docs.unity3d.com/430/Documentation/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html) shell script in your Editor folder which is also called at the end of the build.